# F# properties design

Tags: f#

So when ever im creating some properties in my F# code , as F# doesn't support auto properties , as far as i know. I have to create backing fields and initialize them to null, which doesn't seems right in functional programming terms. For e.g.

```
 let mutable albums : DbSet = null
 let mutable genres : DbSet = null
```

member x.Albums 
    with get() = albums
    and set(value) = albums <- value


member x.Genres
    with get() = genres
    and set (value) = genres <- value

Is there a better way of doing this ?. Many thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: One thing--in addition to Pad's and TomasPetricek's excellent answers: if you're truly trying to be "functional" then I would examine the assumption that you need classes or class-like structures in the first place.  Automatic properties violate good information hiding by exposing the insides of a given class to the rest of the app.  If you need the insides of a class exposed to the rest of the app then maybe you don't need the class in the first place. I guess I'm saying if you really want to think functionally get rid of the idea that everything has to be in a class.

Comment: Oh and one more thing--given what you're working on, you might find this blog posting helpful: http://bugsquash.blogspot.com/2011/11/lenses-in-f.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

F# does not support auto properties when you need a *mutable* property, but it supports a lightweight syntax when you need just a *readonly* property. If you're writing some functional code, then using *readonly* properties might actually be more appropriate:

```
type Music(genres : DbSet, albums : DbSet) = 
  member x.Albums = albums
  member x.Genres = genres
```

This is essentially the same as records suggested by pad, but it may be more appropriate if you want to have better control over how the types look (and how they appear in C#, or for data-binding).

If `DbSet` is a mutable type, then you probably can just use the above type and initialize it just once (you'll still be able to modify the `DbSet` values). If you want to change the `DbSet` value, you can add a method that returns a cloned object:

```
  member x.WithAlbums(newAlbums) = 
    Music(genres, newAlbums)
```

Using `null` or `Unchecked.defaultOf<_>` in F# is considered a very bad practice and you should always try to create fully initlized object. If the value may be missing, you can use `option` type to represent that, but then you have to always write handler for missing value, to make your program safe.

Comment: that exactly what i thought using null cannot be considered a nice practice in a language which has explicit Option types just for this purpose. Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: Does WPF accept option types in favor of explicit nulls?

Answer (score 5):

Unless you're doing something complex, I would recommend to use records instead of classes. Basically, they are classes with extra features: immutability, structural equality, pattern matching, etc:

```
type Playlists = {
    Albums: DbSet;
    Genres: DbSet
    }
```

You can get record's fields easily:

```
let p = {Albums = ...; Genres = ...}
let albums = p.Albums
let genres = p.Genres
```

In default records fields are immutable; you can declare mutable fields in records, but it is considered as a bad practice. Though you cannot set properties, you can create a new record from an old one. Default immutability is normally not a problem, furthermore it makes the code more functional and easier to reason about:

```
   let p = {Albums = a; Genres = g}

   // Create new records by updating one field
   let p1 = {p with Albums = a1} 
   let p2 = {p with Genres = g2}
```

If you insist to create classes, using a constructor with explicit parameters is recommended:

```
type Playlists(a: DbSet, g: DbSet) =
     let mutable albums = a
     let mutable genres = g
     // ...
```

When a default constructor is necessary, you can use `Unchecked.default<'T>` for non nullable fields, or better use their default constructors:

```
 // Set fields using dump values
 let mutable albums = new DbSet()
 let mutable genres = new DbSet()
```

But make sure that you set those fields before actually using them.

Comment: Note that you can also make the fields of a record mutable in the trivial way. Records also have some disadvantages, for example, you have to explicitly set the value of all of its fields in order to construct an object. Another disadvantage is that record types can't inherit and cannot be derived from.

Comment: It's true that records can have mutable fields. But I consider it as a bad design. When you going off that way, classes should be preferred.

Comment: Thanks Pad for your suggestions. Maybe i shall be using records but in my case i think im more interested in a property. But i will rethink about your suggestion and see if i can design my type as a Record.

Comment: @pad: I agree that it's a bad practice, I just mentioned it because the question already featured mutable fields, so I figured it would be relevant information.

Comment: @ShdNx: agree, I updated the answer to mention mutable record fields.

Answer (score 5):

FYI - auto-properties are planned for F# 3.0. See the [preview documentation <sup>[MSDN]</sup>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd483467(v=vs.110).aspx). Looks like your example would become:

```
type Music() =
  member val Albums : DbSet = null with get, set
  member val Genres : DbSet = null with get, set
```

Comment: apparently these things aren't allowed to be private

Comment: `member val GroupBox1:GroupBox = new GroupBox()` throws saying `Additional information: The initialization of an object or value resulted in an object or value being accessed recursively before it was fully initialized.` This constructor seems to run after the class holding the auto-property's constructor.

Comment: Sure they are: `member val private ...`